# P-values in Orange

Tags: regression, orange

I'm new to orange and struggling to find p-values, using different regression tools.

It seems the outputs are only coefficients. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a bit more? regression tools or techniques?

Comment: To clarify, I am using the orange3 GUI and dragging the linear regression tool onto my file (data). When I attach a data table to the regression the only output I can get on the data table is a coefficient value.

Comment: can you share some screenshot?

Comment: https://imgur.com/ZCWIC9l

Comment: https://imgur.com/HJJyRP4